# Making a class that will contain a subclass that can be different classes depending on the need

Tags: c#, class, subclass

I'm unsure how to go about implementing this particular idea of I have a class lets call it EnhancedUserInput that will have some variables that all of the input types will have and a particular subclass depending on the need during operation so some extra variables and a list so for example sub classes of it would be MultipleChoice which would have MinSelection, MaxSelection and a list of a type called option with their own variables ect and then another possible sub class called ExplicitAgreement which would have the variables inputLabel1, inputLabel2 and a list of type BinaryInput which would have their own variables.

So far from what I understand the best way going about this would be to have some type of generic variable? I'll show some code to try and help get what it is I need across but was just wondering is there an easy way of doing this that I am unaware of?

```
public class EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public string Title { get; set;}

    public bool ResponseOptional { get; set;}

    public string CancelLabel { get; set;}

    public string SubmitLabel { get; set}

    // this is where I am unsure of how to go about it
    public object inputType
    {
        MultipleChoice
        ExplicitAgreement
    }
}

public class MultipleChoice
{
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> Options { get; set; }

    public int MinSelected { get; set; }

    public int MaxSelected { get; set; }

}

public class ExplicitAgreement
{
    public List<BinaryInputOption> Buttons { get; set; }

    public string InputLabel1 { get; set; }

    public string InputLabel2 { get; set; }
}
```

what would be the best path for this solution I can think of some possible ways but they would be a bit figity and was wondering if there are any simple ways?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/).  Input Type should be a property: `public T InputType {get; set;}`

Comment: Would the fact that the input type can have a different number of variables be a problem. For example whenever I am trying to assign things like model.inputType.Options[0].add(Option) vs model.inputType.Buttons[0].add(Button) does the fact there are different variables get figured out by the IDE (just wanting to make sure before i head down that path)

Comment: Constructs like "model.inputType.Buttons[0].add(Button)" have a certain smell ... A more "oldschool" alternative to Generics would be interfaces ... but let's step back: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean Code smell. The user of such construct has to know way too much about the datastructure. You'll end up in high complex, very badly maintainable code.

Comment: Yeah I do feel like it'll be a bit of a jungle and so was wondering if there were a simpler solution to what I was currently thinking :/ .

Comment: Inferring from comments to answers: Are you trying to build some sort of UI Configurator / Designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve Harris's inheritance suggestion is good. Your original option to use Composition can work just fine, too:

```
public class EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public string Title { get; set;}

    public bool ResponseOptional { get; set;}

    public string CancelLabel { get; set;}

    public string SubmitLabel { get; set; }

    public object InputData { get; set; }
}
```

The only problem is that consumers of your code need to know that `InputData` can be one of several different types, and you presumably need logic to `switch` on their type. You can add comments to the property to give people a hint, or you can use a library like LanguageExt, which provides an `Either` type:

```
public class EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public string Title { get; set;}

    public bool ResponseOptional { get; set;}

    public string CancelLabel { get; set;}

    public string SubmitLabel { get; set; }

    public Either<MultipleChoice, ExplicitAgreement> InputData { get; set; }
}
```

This makes it much more obvious which types `InputData` can be, but would get very unwieldy if you have more than two possibilities.

You could also declare an interface that `InputData` must implement, which would make it easier for developers to find all the types that are intended to be used there. But an empty interface is considered to be a code smell because it indicates you're using interfaces for something they weren't really intended for.

Another option I've found to work well is to define an `enum` type to help identify which different types of input data you can have:

```
public class EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public string Title { get; set;}

    public bool ResponseOptional { get; set;}

    public string CancelLabel { get; set;}

    public string SubmitLabel { get; set; }

    public InputType InputType { get; set; }

    public object InputData { get; set; }
}

public enum InputType { MultipleChoice, ExplicitAgreement }
```

This gives your business logic a specific set of possible types that you can `switch` your logic on, and works particularly well when the class is going to be serialized and deserialized, because then you can tell the deserializer which specific type of object to deserialize `InputData` to.

There are lots of options, each with their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that you may have this the wrong way around. Maybe what you want is to just use class inheritance?

```
public class EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public bool ResponseOptional { get; set;}
    public string CancelLabel { get; set;}
    public string SubmitLabel { get; set}
}

public class MultipleChoice : EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public List<MultipleChoiceOption> Options { get; set; }
    public int MinSelected { get; set; }
    public int MaxSelected { get; set; }
}

public class ExplicitAgreement : EnhancedCustomerInput
{
    public List<BinaryInputOption> Buttons { get; set; }
    public string InputLabel1 { get; set; }
    public string InputLabel2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing it this way but would that require making different methods to pass and build for each of my subclasses the end goal is to use this to collect input from the user to build a XML string to be sent away and so was hoping to get the base to be constant and having the input type subclass change depending on which input type is needed (apologies for poor explanations my heads fried atm)

Comment: If you could add a concise explanation of your actual goal in the question, a more sophisticated suggestion could be made. I don't see why Steve's approach would go against your goal as described in your above comment. @C.Dodds

Comment: the model gets initialized as a type when the program starts but the input type isnt chosen until the user chooses what input type they want and the corresponding input fields will appear for their choice so for example a bunch of text boxes for what text to display with the buttons. and because I wont know what input type the user will select on program start up I was hoping to make it dynamic and allow the structure of it to change once the user makes a choice (if thats possible) I was thinking generics

Comment: Is that Winforms or WPF or ... ? @C.Dodds

Comment: @C.Dodds: Based on these comments, it sounds like the last of the options I provide in my answer would probably be a good fit. You can bind a dropdown menu to the enum property, and switch which type of object you provide as sub-options based on the user's input. When deserializing, you have access to a value that defines which type you need to deserialize the InputData to.